# Default vs LLAP Hive Connection HiveQL Syntax, difference?

Tags: sql, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hiveql

I run queries using LLAP JDBC Connection string, but recently we had to change to Hive Default connection and some queries that aren't working now, there's a common error:

*[Code: 40000, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:54 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification*

Is there any syntax difference using LLAP vs Default connection? Why does my query works in LLAP connection?

Comment: So, what is the mysterious "input" inside the `max()` aggregation function?

Comment: I don't think there's a syntax difference. Maybe functions added or removed